# How to Download zip file from FireBase Storage with angularFire?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, firebase-storage, angularfire

I'm here again thanks to FireBase, basically I need to download the download.zip file from the Storage from a button in the html.
Following the angular/fire documentation I got the following result:

```
profileUrl!: Observable<string | null>;

download(){
const ref = this.storage.ref('atualizadores/download.zip');
this.profileUrl = ref.getDownloadURL();
console.log(this.profileUrl)}
```

At the end in the console.log return an Observable, which I'm not sure what to do.

What is the next step for clicking the button and downloading the file?

Comment: Never done this but if its an observable do subscribe so this.profileUrl.subscribe((url) => { 
console.log(url)}); This you can download any url you download from the browser

Comment: @misha130 Apparently it's the correct path, it actually appears in the console when doing the way you commented. Now it's time to understand how to click the button and download the file.